# dealing with an inspected list of tuples

Tags: elixir

I have a list of tuples (representing an http request headers),
before saving it to the database, I inspected it.
For example, an original value:

`[{"Content-Type", "application/json"}, {"x-request-id", "fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la"}]`

is saved as:

`"[{\"Content-Type\", \"application/json\"}, {\"x-request-id\", \"fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la\"}]"`

Is there a way to bring these values back to there original type (when loading from the db)?

Comment: Is it saved as JSON string?

Comment: no, it is a list of tuples, not a map, so couldn't use a JSON stringify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Code.eval_string/1` for that.
Here is a pipe with the full trip into and back from your DB.

```
[{"C", "json"}, {"x", "fa"}]
|> inspect
|> Code.eval_string
|> fn {recovered, []} -> recovered end.()
```

Just be careful to prevent code injections!!!

Comment: Please, don't. As @Xmul mentioned, there is a possibility for a code injection. Your data looks like coming from the http header, so from the outside world. What if someone put something like `"System.cmd(\"rm\", [\"-rf\", \"/\"])"` there?

Answer (score 1):

you can make a workaround like this:

```
your_string = "[{\"Content-Type\", \"application/json\"}, {\"x-request-id\", \"fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la\"}]"

your_string
|> String.split(~r/\"?\"/) 
|> Enum.filter(fn value -> value not in ["[{", ", ", "}, {", "}]"] end) 
|> Enum.chunk_every(2) 
|> Enum.map(fn [key, value] -> {key, value} end)
```

:D

Comment: you can use 
   headers |> Enum.into(%{}) |> Poison.encode! 
to store
and
   headers_from_db |> Poison.decode! |> Enum.into([])
to load back

Answer (score 1):

You may use `:erlang.term_to_binary/1` to encode any term and save in in the DB as some BLOB:

```
iex(1)> t = [{"Content-Type", "application/json"}, {"x-request-id", "fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la"}]
[
  {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
  {"x-request-id", "fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la"}
]
iex(3)> encoded = :erlang.term_to_binary(t)
<<131, 108, 0, 0, 0, 2, 104, 2, 109, 0, 0, 0, 12, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110,
  116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 109, 0, 0, 0, 16, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97,
  116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110, 104, 2, 109, 0, ...>>
```

Then use `binary_to_term/1` to get your list back:

```
iex(4)> :erlang.binary_to_term(encoded)
[
  {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
  {"x-request-id", "fatlud3104arjj91jtig2qrj3u7320la"}
]
```

If you don't want to save the binary, but rather a text, you may additionally encode it with Base64

```
iex(4)> t |> :erlang.term_to_binary() |> Base.encode64()
"g2wAAAACaAJtAAAADENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZW0AAAAQYXBwbGljYXRpb24vanNvbmgCbQAAAAx4LXJlcXVlc3QtaWRtAAAAIGZhdGx1ZDMxMDRhcmpqOTFqdGlnMnFyajN1NzMyMGxhag=="
```